# Get Type of Generic Class in stream

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, stream

im trying to get a simple networking program working by Sending different Broadcast Messages.

First my Message Class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Message<T>
{
    public enum MessageType
    {
        Broadcast,
        Unicast
    }

    private T _payload;
    private readonly MessageType _type;
    private readonly DateTime _createdOn = DateTime.Now;

    public MessageType Type
    {
        get { return _type; }
    }

    public T Payload
    {
        get { return _payload; }
        set { _payload = value; }
    }

    public DateTime CreatedOn
    {
        get { return _createdOn; }
    }
    private Message() { }
    private Message(T setPayload, MessageType type)
    {
        _payload = setPayload;
        _type = type;
    }

    public class Builder
    {
        private readonly T _payload;
        private MessageType _messageType = MessageType.Unicast;

        public Builder(T payload)
        {
            _payload = payload;
        }

        public Builder Broadcast()
        {
            _messageType = MessageType.Broadcast;
            return this;
        }

        public Message<T> Build()
        {
            Message<T> result = new Message<T>(_payload, _messageType);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then i have my Classes:

```
[Serializable()]
public class HelloWorld
{
    public String HelloString { get; set; }
    public HelloWorld() { }
}

[Serializable()]
class HelloWorld2
{
    public String HelloString2 { get; set; }
    public HelloWorld2() { }
}
```

Now i have two methods `SendHelloWorld()` and `SendHelloWorld2()`.

I´m reserving the first 32 bytes of my Memorystream for a string which Contains the typeName.

```
internal void SendHelloWorld()
    {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();

        var message = new Message<HelloWorld>.Builder(helloWorld).Broadcast().Build();

        // implement broadcasting
        Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Messages.HelloWorld");

        memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        SerializationService.Serialize(memoryStream, message);
        SendBroadcastMessage(memoryStream);
    }
```

SendBroadCastMessage just converts the stream to byte[] and Broadcasts the Message.

When Receiving them i have to check if the Message is Typeof HelloWorld or HelloWorld2

But i havent found a way yet to get it working, string isn accepted as type, and i dont want to work with switch-case, cause there will be many more types of Messages added afterwards.

```
private void UdpListener()
    {
        UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(9050, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        IPEndPoint iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

        Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(listener.Receive(ref iep));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
        inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 32);
        string type = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,0,32);

        Message<type> message = _service.Deserialize<Message<HelloWorld>>(inputStream);

        Received(message.Payload);

        listener.Close();
    }
```

Comment: too long to read, you may simplify your problem in simple and short words

Comment: ur just to lame to read

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it Working just changed the UdpListener:

```
private void UdpListener()
    {
        _iep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);
        _listener = new UdpClient(_iep);

        while (true)
        {
            Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(_listener.Receive(ref _iep));

            dynamic msg = _service.Deserialize<object>(inputStream);

            Received(msg.Payload);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all Answers

Answer (score 1):

Question: What is `SerializationService` ?

Hopefully you're using .NET standard serialization and more precisely: BinaryFormatter.
If you're using SoapFormatter then generics won't work.
If you're using something other than these 2 please tell us what kind of serialization service is it.

If the answer is favorable (BinaryFormatter), you could go the following route.

Proposal:

1) Make this abstract class and make yours extend it like so:

```
 [Serializable()]
 public abstract class AbstractMessage {

     public object Payload { get { return this.GetPayload(); } }
     protected abstract object GetPayload();

 }

 [Serializable()]
 public class Message<T> : AbstractMessage
 {
     // .... etc ....
     public new T Payload
     {
         get { return _payload; }
         set { _payload = value; }
     }
     // .... etc ....
     protected override object GetPayload() { return this.Payload; }
 }
```

2) Stop doing this:

```
byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Messages.HelloWorld");
memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

3) and this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 32);
string type = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer,0,32);
```

(because .NET serialization is more self explanatory than you'll ever be
and let it do the hard work for you)

4) In your receiving application, do something like this

```
private void UdpListener()
{
    // .... etc ....

    //object obj = _service.Deserialize<object>(inputStream);

    // this should now work perfectly (as long as you stopped writing the string into stream
    // from the client)
    object obj = (new BinaryFormatter()).Deserialize(inputStream);

    if (!(obj is AbstractMessage))
       // complain to yourself via exception, log or other things

    var message = obj as AbstractMessage;
    object payload = message.Payload;

    // here you can access on of two things:
    Type payloadType = payload.GetType();
    Type aproximatelySameType = message.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];

    // and you can honor this payload like an object or by casting it to whatever
    // you desire, or by reflection, or whatever
    Received(message.Payload);

    listener.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yes im Serializing with binaryFormatter, but i get an error if i try to deserialize the object. Unable to cast object of type 'Grid.Node.Messages.Message`1[Grid.Node.Messages.HelloWorld]' to type 'Grid.Node.Messages.Message`1[System.Object]'. Will look tomorrow for it

Comment: The method you mentioned in the UDP Listener: `_service.Deserialize<object>(inputStream);` does a bit **too much**. You didn't tell us what it does and I made an assumption. Please check the latest edit. Btw: The error you're getting is actually **great news !!!**. It is telling you that an instance of the `Message<HelloWorld>` has been successfully deserialized and now exists in the heap. The cast is the problem. And that cast is performed by the method `Deserialize<T>` which you didn't show us.

Comment: I changed `object obj = _service.Deserialize<object>(inputStream);` with `object obj = (new BinaryFormatter()).Deserialize(inputStream);` and it should work great, as long as you're not sending the leading string from the client anymore

Comment: Just one more Question: I want to cast the var Message in the payloadType. for example if var message is type HelloWorld i want to cast like this:    var newMessage = (Message<HelloWorld>))message;   But didnt found a way jet, Sry dont know how codeblocks are written in comments

Comment: Do something like this: `var message = obj as AbstractMessage; if (message.Payload is HelloWorld) { HelloWorld obj1 = (HelloWorld)message.Payload; var moreSpecificMsg = (Message<HelloWorld>)message; HelloWorld obj2_equalToObj1 = moreSpecificMsg.Payload; } else { //blah }`. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: not realy, cause i will have many more message types and i dont want to change the code everytime a new message is added.

Comment: If you have 3 classes. The first one is a Cherry and it has own property: `int Diameter`, the second one is a Galaxy and it has a property `List<Star> Stars` and you have a Camera which has no properties but has one method `Bitmap TakePhoto(double exposureTime)` How exactly are you going to work with all of these 3 classes without writing 3 completely distinct and very specific pieces of code.... I'm guessing that you're asking, how could you automatically dispatch a call from a generic place to 3 more specific places. But those 3 specific places **must** exist.

Comment: Solved my Problem with a dynamic var. after getting my inputStream just one Line of Code needed ^^ no need for abstract class.    `dynamic msg = _service.Deserialize<object>(inputStream);`    and now my    `msg.Payload`   is the right type so i can do    `Received(msg.Payload)`

Answer (score 0):

You can get a type from a string by using the Static method [GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

```
var myType = Type.GetType("SomeType");
```

However, unless that type is currently in the executing assembly, then you will have to use a [fully qualified type name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx). Otherwise you will get an exception.

If you want to see what the fully qualified assembly name for your type is you can inspect the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) property of a Type object.

```
typeof(HelloWorld).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Comment: Tryed for string temp = "Messages.HelloWorld" but myType is a NullReference. if i take string temp = "Messages.HelloWorld, Grid.Node" Grid.Node is my assembly name, its also a NullReference.